How does qiskit implement a given superposition in the actual quantum computer?
My question is phrased in 2 parts:

Is there a quantum circuit to implement the following 4-qubit state: $$\frac{1}{2}(|1000 \rangle + |0100 \rangle + |0010 \rangle + |0001 \rangle)$$

When we use the Qiskit Statevector class and pass a list of coefficients to generate a state, how does Qiskit implement the superposition? Even if it can do the superimposition on a software level, if such a state is to be initialized on an actual quantum computer, how can it be done? Is there a general circuit construction to create the following general superposed state:$$|\psi \rangle = \sum_i c_i |i \rangle$$ Where $i \in \{0,1 \}^n$, is one of the n-qubit computational basis state bitstrings.


Edit: I am not asking for Qiskit circuits to code up a general state. I am asking for a gate-based construction, if it exists, for general states (or how states are initialized in an actual quantum computer)

For the first question, see here

@Egretta.Thula Thanks a lot!

If you're interested in the details of how to derive this type of circuit, I have a notebook with a step by step description here

you can edit the post and title to clarify what you're actually trying to ask. Also note that each post should contain a single question, you can ask different questions in different posts

As the first question is answered in comments, I'll only answer the second question here.
To initialize your custom state, you can use either initialize() or prepare_state() methods from the QuantumCircuit class. In this functions you just have to give your custom statevector and the circuit will be initialized to that particular state. For example to initialize a circuit in bell state:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
 
circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
circuit.prepare_state(Statevector([1/sqrt(2), 0, 0, -1/sqrt(2)]), circuit.qubits)
circuit.draw()

You can also use initialize similarly. (look at the links provided)
Hope this helps!

I think I was not clear enough with my question. I understand that there is a circuit I can "code" up on Qiskit to initialize any statevector. What I asked is: how is such a general state implemented in an actual Quantum computer, either using gates, or any other methods?

If you read the documentation for StatePreparation, you can see they provide the reference for where the procedure for state preparation comes from: Shende, Bullock, Markov. Synthesis of Quantum Logic Circuits (2004)
